# can I add link in the columns series RadHtmlChart

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-charting

I am using Telerik. I want to add a link in the columns series, I use the follow chart: RadHtmlChart. How can I do that?

thanks for yours comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the OnClientSeriesClicked event and navigate the browser: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-client-side-onclientseriesclicked.html.

You can add HTML only in tooltips' template if you like: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-client-templates-for-tooltips-and-labels-execute-javascript-and-display-html.html.